# SqlConnection localhost failed username

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, sqlconnection

This is my first time trying to use a database in ASP.Net, and I have a problem here:

My database is on my computer (localhost), and it throws an exception on me when I click the "submit" button :

> SQLException was unhandled by user code.    Login failed for user ".

```
    protected void Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server = localhost ;uid=; Password= database = Movies;");
        connection.Open();
        //FirstName***********
        string firstName = UsernameTextBox.Text;
        string sqlquery = ("INSERT INTO [Movie] (FirstName) VALUES (' " +FirstNameTextBox.Text + " ' ");

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery , connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", firstName);
```

Since the server is on my computer, I dont have any username, right?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need a username and password, or else you need to use integrated security, which means that your windows credentials are used.

You can add integrated security to your connection as follows:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server = localhost ;integrated security=SSPI; database = Movies;");
```

A good resource for connection strings is http://www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: although it doesnt work .   it says : "Keywords not supporeted" , and refering to the integrated_security

Comment: @user1054375 use "Integrated Security" without the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

SQL server always requires a username, whether it's on your machine or a remote machine.

I'd suggest looking www.asp.net or try Google to find out how you configure your patricular version of SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Check this [site](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Providers/sqlconnection) for connectionstrings if you have problem with formating the connectionstring